# 'int' object is not iterable no matter what I do

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

So I'm trying to code for a function that determines what day of the week you were born on. One of the functions I'm trying to create looks like this:

```
def days_in_year(x):
    y = 0
    n = x-1
    for years in n:
        if years % 4 == 0:
            y = y + 3
        elif y % 4 != 0:
            y = y + 1
    return y
```

This returns 'TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable' no matter what I do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `for years in range(n):`

Comment: Please provide a sample input and the desired output.

Comment: You'll save yourself time (and probably frustration) if you look at the builtin `calendar` and `datetime` modules - for instance - it looks like you're trying to re-write `calendar.is_leap`... for `days_in_year = 366 if calendar.is_leap(x) else 365` and to get the day of birth, something like: `format(datetime(2002, 9, 3), '%A')` -> `Tuesday` is all you need

Comment: This must be an XYZ problem already.  I am not sure what the `for` loop should do either, the days in year also looks very fishy... but all in all the fix for `'int' object is not iterable` could be found with some googling...

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the for loop to

```
for years in range(n):
```

range() generates a list of numbers, which is generally used to iterate over with for loops.

Answer (score 0):

to expand on my comment - the `for` loop you are using there `for years in n:` iterates over every element of `n`.

you defined `n` as `n = x-1` which is an integer, so you can't iterate over it because it doesn't have any elements. you need to generate a list using `range(n)`

eg:

```
range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

which you can then iterate over. Hope that helps.